# How do I state an ARIMA(0,1,4)x(0,1,1)12 in terms of Yt etc and not in terms of the backshift operator

Tags: time-series, arima

I would like to state an $\text{ARIMA}\left\{(0,1,4)\times(0,1,1)\right\}$ model (written in format $(p,d,q)\times(P,D,Q)$ model without using the backshift operator.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: there are some nice examples in this website http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim.htm , you can modify to suit  your problem. This question looks like a home work, can you add a tag self study and modify your question to include what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

I took your model form and entered it into AUTOBOX and asked for the model to be presented as an ADL (Auto-regressive Distributed Model ) or PDL (Polynomial Distributed Model).
[image] .  The actual coefficients depend of course on the data BUT you get the idea that Y is on the left-hand side and lags of Y and lags of the error terms are on the right-hand side. This was programmed so that the equation could be "sold" or "explained" to the customer , leading to acceptance of the results.

It is sometimes possible to express the equation as a pure right-hand side where there are mo error terms just lags of Y. The problem arises when the order of this pure lag model exceeds the number of observations. In Box-Jenkins language this is called the Pi weights.
I have shown these weights up to lag 50. In effect an ARIMA model is simply a weighted sum of the past much like an old-fashioned  k period weighted average. The second value shown .85284 is the weight of the first lag of Y , etc.. Also note that the weights are not decreasing in absolute value

```
lag 12  1.148
lag 24  1.1699
lag 36  1.1732
lag 48  1.1737
```

suggesting that this model when applied to the data set that I used here violates the invertability requirements as the past past is more important than the recent past.

[image]